# Can you save a image file as a URL into a database using node js?

Tags: node.js, multer, uploading

Currently, in my project, I am saving image files to MongoDB using multer. I am doing this by converting the image into base64 format and then saving that data. This works, but it takes up a lot of storage in the database, slowing down my application. I was wondering if there was a way to convert the file into a URL and then save that URL into the database. 
This would turn something like this: iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAyAAAAMgCAIAAABU... 
Into something like this: something.com/imageurl.

Here is my current code:

```
var multer = require("multer");
var upload = multer({ 
    storage: multer.memoryStorage(),
    limits: {fileSize: 1 * 2048 * 2048},
    fileFilter: function fileFilter(req, file, cb){
    if(file.mimetype !== 'image/png' | "image/jpg" | "image/jpeg"){
       return cb(new Error('Something went wrong'), false);
    }
    cb(null, true);
    }
}).fields([{ name: 'fileone', maxCount: 1 }, { name: 'filetwo', maxCount: 1 }]);
module.exports = upload;
```

```
app.post("/create",  function(req, res){
upload(req, res, function(err){
    if(err){
        res.render("create", {msg: "Error: Please Keep each file under 1mb and only upload PNG, JPG, or JPEG images"});
    } else{
        var fileOne = req.files["fileone"][0].buffer.toString("base64");
        var fileTwo = req.files["filetwo"][0].buffer.toString("base64");
        var title = req.body.title;
        var newPosts = {title: title, fileOne: fileOne, fileTwo: fileTwo}
        Post.create(newPosts, function(err, newlyCreated){
            if (err){
                console.log(err);
            } else{
                res.redirect("/posts/" + newlyCreated._id);
        }
        });
    }
});
```

})

Answer (score 1):

You can save the file to disk and put the path to the file into the database:

Instead of using `multer.memoryStorage`, you can use `multer.diskStorage`.

In your `upload` method `req.files` will then contain an array to the paths.